# Remove certain keys and values from associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array that looks like this:

```
[['title'= >'my title','time'=>'14:00','date'=>'feb 2'],['title'= >'another','time'=>'14:00','date'=>'feb 2']]
```

Now I wish to remove all **time** and **date** keys from the arrays and also rename the **title** to **text** so it looks like this:

```
[['text'= >'my title'],['text'= >'another title']]
```

I have tried to use

```
$tags = array_map(function($tag) {
          return array(
              'text' => $tag['title'],
          );
      }, $tags);
```

But I cant get it to work

Comment: Can’t see an issue with array_map. Probably due to nested array.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel solution:

```
collect($array)->transform(function($i) { return ['text' => $i['title']]; })->toArray();
```

Comment: Still needs to rename `title` index to `text` though.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your collections,

```
$mycollection = $myModel->get();

return $mycollection->map(function($row){
    return [
        'text' => $row->title,
    ];
});
```

Or you can use Fractal: http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't specific to Laravel, but since you mention it:

Use the `collect()` helper and it's methods for convenience. You'll want to look at `pull`, `map`, and maybe `transform` in particular.

If you don't use it then `unset` will delete the index you want from the array.

Alternatively, just create a new array:

```
$a = []

foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $a[] = ['text' => $tag['title']];
}
```

edit: fix

Comment: Example will result in one item. `$a['text']`

Answer (score 0):

```
$newTags = [];

foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $newTags[] = [['text'] => $tag['title']];
}
$tags = $newTags;
```